# How can I do an OR operation on the values of facet search? (without Solr)

Tags: search

I'm using the Search API with Facet Search to filter my nodes in a view. How can I do a OR operation here? Can't find this setting.

Ex. If I have a facet filter of colors and I select the colors yellow and green, I will only see the products with yellow AND green. I want to show all the products with the yellow tag OR green tag.

Comment: there is an option to expose operator have you tried that?